# new to cross domain CORS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, cors

I am new to this thing, so there is some questions I wanted to ask after looking up bunch of site that related to CORS.

First of all, lets say i have http://domain1.com that has a ajax call to http://domain2.com, I look up on http://enable-cors.org/server.html it say that I will have to add

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

this response to my page header or add this setting to web.config on the root directory of my application, but I was confused, should I add the response header to domain1 or domain2 application? My guess was add to domain2, but I cannot be sure because I don't have the required things to test it.

Furthermore, what if domain2.com were in https, means I am calling from http to https, will this works?

and how about IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it on http://domain2.com because [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is permission for http://domain1.com to get information from http://domain2.com.
Note that (*) symbol means that domain allows access to everyone, so you need to be careful with that. Better option would be:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.com
```

It work fine for IE and for https:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.com, https://domain1.com
```

Take a look for more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control).