# Querying A wcf rest service with jquery (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I have created a WCF rest service that is to be consumed by jquery. The service is hosted in my local machine. The service seems to work only if I am using a GET verb. If i use any other i get the 405 (Method not allowed ) error. Id like to post a json object to my service using jquery.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate="Contact", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [Description("Send contact us message.")]
    string Log(Someobject object);
}
```

CLient Code:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "PUT",
            url: "http://localhost/servicename/ContactUs.svc/Contact",
            data: JSON.Stringify(jsonObject),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData:true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Ping" + data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Failed to ping server" + error);
            }
        });
```

Web Config

```
<behavior name="ContactUsBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ContactUsEndPointBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

<services>
  <service name="servicename.ContactUs" behaviorConfiguration="ContactUsBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="JSONPBinding" contract="servicename.IContactUs" behaviorConfiguration="ContactUsEndPointBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

See `dataType: "jsonp"` only work with `type:"GET"`. so if you are using `jsonp` then you have to use this:

```
type: "GET", // or remove it, if not available then "GET" is default set
.......
dataType: "jsonp",
```

### [Another answer which can help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684221/1059101)

---

After your comment i suggest you to do this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET", // change to GET
     url: "/servicename/ContactUs.svc/Contact", // remove the http://localhost
     data: JSON.Stringify(jsonObject),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     processData:true,
     dataType: "json",   // change jsonp to json
     success: function (data) {
         alert("Ping" + data);
     },
     error: function (error) {
         alert("Failed to ping server" + error);
     }
});
```

---

Or if you still want to use `http://localhost` then you have to enable **cors** at your serverside.

### [A post about enabling CORS *(Cross Origin Resource Sharing.)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595232/1059101)

Comment: My aim is to send an object to the server as a parameter hence im using a type:put or post. If i remove jsonp and use type post or put I get the following: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.'I also get (options {my service url} 405 method not allowed